# Delete rows by creation date and not by timestamp in HBase

Tags: java, hbase, ttl

I've got an HBase table with rows that are sometimes getting updated (so are their timestamps obviously)

I was wondering if there's any built-in way for performing TTL on rows according to the row's creation date? (so if I updated a row with a newer version it wouldn't affect the deletion time of that row?)

Just an example: put 'row1' with value 'aaa' on 20/04/2016
on a table 'test' with TTL of 2 days and then if I perform another put of 'row1' the next day the row will still be deleted on 22/04/2016 (and not on the 23/04/2016 like what the regular TTL functionality does)

If there's no built-in way, what would be a good way of performing this with my own code (Java, scala or whatever)? I don't think I can retrieve a full table scan into memory, is there any way to lazy-load the entire table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

> ColumnFamilies can set a TTL length in seconds, and HBase will automatically delete rows once the expiration time is reached. This applies to all versions of a row - even the current one. The TTL time encoded in the HBase for the row is specified in UTC.

Based on this,  you can set a ttl on a CF,  and the row will be erase once the ttl is reached. Every update on this row will reset the timer, so to not reset the row you need to overwrite the last write using the same timestamp.

Comment: Whitefret, thanks for your comment but as I said what I need is not the regular TTL ability since I may update that row later on, What I want is the TTL to be performed on the creation date and not on the timestamp

Comment: @Gideon did you try it? because it is ambigous when the timer starts. (don't have the hand on a cluster right now)

Comment: I did. I inserted a row 'row1' on a specific time with TTL of 30 seconds and if I reinserted that row it postponed the deletion time accordingly (if I don't reinsert the TTL is working fine)

Comment: @Gideon Would it work if you don't do updates but overwrites? You use the timestamp already stored to Write with the same timestamp. You Will have to write before any reads though

Comment: Mmm @Whitefret that might work. I'm not next to my work computer at the moment but once I will be I'll give it a try and update if it works or not

Comment: yes it actually works. I can't use that solution as it is since I have other constraints that I didn't mention but I found a solution for my exact problem as well. Thanks for the tip. I suggest you update your answer so I can accept it as the solution to the problem in the question